# Manually terminating a systemd service that shuts down on complete

Tags: systemd

I have a periodic task that runs on a cloud VM. The machine type is quite expensive, so I have a systemd unit service that launches on boot, runs a script and then shuts the machine off to save money. This works as designed.

I've had trouble doing maintenance to the machine because if I login and issue a `service [] stop` command, of course the system shuts down immediately (as it's supposed to).

I think I should be able to use `OnFailure` for this, but I'd also like the system to shutdown if the script fails for some reason (rather than leave the VM spinning in the event of a crash). Or some use of `ExecStop`?

There would be three cases:

- Process executes and terminates properly (e.g. exit code 0), system power off
- Process crashes (e.g. exit code != 0), system power off
- Service terminated/paused by user? system stays on

Simple solution is to give the service a grace period of a minute before starting, login, disable, reboot (because the service has already started), perform maintenance tasks and then re-enable. But this seems a bit clunky. The service definition is below, for reference.

```
[Unit]
Description="Run job"
After=network.target
StartLimitInterval=200
StartLimitBurst=30
OnFailure=systemd-poweroff.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60
ExecStart=/my/script.sh
ExecStopPost=sudo systemctl poweroff -i
User=foo

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Just a note the script is run as a normal user due to the environment setup rather than anything security conscious, hence the sudo here (the account is specifically given passwordless sudo rights for poweroff).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `poweroff` in an `ExecStopPost` action, move it to a separate service. That is, make your "Run job" service look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description="Run job"
After=network.target
Requires=my-poweroff.service
Before=my-poweroff.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
ExecStart=/my/script.sh
User=foo

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that we're using `Type=oneshot` instead of `Type=simple`, because this way the service isn't "started" until the script completes. This is important because we're triggering the poweroff through a `Requires=`/`Before=` dependency; using `Type=simple`, this job and the poweroff job would start *at the same time*. Using `Type=oneshot` means that the poweroff job won't run until this service has exited.

Then in `my-poweroff.service`, you have:

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=!/run/nopoweroff

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl poweroff -i
```

Now, if you want to prevent the `poweroff`, just `touch /run/nopoweroff` before your "Run job" service has finished.